# How to tell java's TreeSet or HashMap that the order by which its contenst are indexed is the insertion order(don't want LinkedHashMap)?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Eg; I want my TreeSet / HashMap to store 1,19,3,4,2,0 in that order since it is the order they are added to the map.

I hear that LinkedHashMap is the go-to solution. But my question is, can we produce the same result with TreeSet/HashMap, with some modification introduced to comparedTo()?

Comment: I think that's what's LinkedHashMap is for

Comment: How do I tell my dog that he's a cat?

Comment: What benefit is there of creating an alternative implementation that mimics an actual implementation?

Comment: I don't see the benefit of creating a completely new implementation, but if it is possible with a few modification (like return 1 or - 1 or whatever), then this is something good to know.

Comment: Why would you try to hack another `Map` implementation, when [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) already exists and does *exactly* what you're asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You cannot do that.  You must use `LinkedHashMap` or another custom map implementation; `TreeMap` and `HashMap` cannot support insertion order.

Comment: I thought like maybe with some clever coding in comparedTo().... Thanks!

Comment: Nothing that makes the map actually usable.

Comment: He said TreeSet or HashMap.  TreeSet would still be perfectly usable.  I could think of one use case where the insertion order of TreeMap (not HashMap) would be useful: if you are using timestamps as the key in order to range query results into NavigableMap, then the insertion order would be preserved as a by-product.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a very very complicated compareTo(...) method, but it would involve basically keeping track of the state of the tree yourself, manually, somewhere external to the tree. That's just re-creating a LinkedHashMap without using a LinkedHashMap. Same thing, but much more complex and hard to read and maintain code. No reason to do that.

Comment: The easiest I can think of is, in the function that adds to the map, there will be a variable that keeps track of no. elements added to that map so far, and assign that value to each instance's variable (eg; int myindex). Then comparedTo should work. But this is neither portable nor feasible.

Comment: Ha!  You beat me to the punch.  Yeah, the fact that a user can call mySet.remove() makes a simple integer insertion order problematic.  You would probably need to use date/time stamps for the insertionOrder object.

Answer (score -1):

"You cannot do that."  Well, you can.  All you need to do is add the insertion order to the object you're storing and account for it in the compareTo or comparator.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    int returnValue = 0;
    if(o instanceof InsertionObject) {
        InsertionObject newObject = (InsertionObject)o;
        if(this.insertionOrder != newObject.insertionOrder) {
            if(this.insertionOrder < newObject.insertionOrder) {
                returnValue = -1;
            }
            else {
                returnValue = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Insert error message here.");
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I'm not saying you *should,* but you *could.*  This smells like an interview question or a homework problem, so they probably are just testing to see if the poster understands what is going on inside the underlying collections?

Comment: This only works for custom types, and makes the map basically unusable for queries.

Comment: I was thinking of TreeSet specifically, but yeah.  There's no *logical* reason you would ever do this.  That's why I'm assuming it's an interview question meant to test someone's understanding of the underlying structures.